# list of all the permutations and combinations for 2 strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell, combinations, permutation

Lets take a word

```
qwerty
```

What I want is I need to insert periods (dots .) between the string. It can be any other character also.

For example,

```
q.werty
qw.erty
qwe.rty
qwer.ty
qwert.y
```

The above is for 1 period or dot. So 1 period combination for a 5 letter string will generate 5 outputs. (N-1)

Now for 2 periods (2 dots) (2 examples only):

```
q.w.erty
q.we.rty
q.wer.ty
q.wert.y
qw.e.rty
qw.er.ty
qw.ert.y
qwe.r.ty
qwe.rt.y
qwer.t.y
```

and so on..

NOTE: There must not be 2 consecutive dots between 2 letters in the string. Also, there must not be a period before starting character and/or after ending character.

Can anyone provide a Shell Script (sh, bash) for the above to list all the possible combinations and permutations. I have tried Googling and didn't find any worthwhile content to refer.

EDIT: Any help on how to start this on bash shell script would be great...

Comment: "Can anyone provide a Shell Script" - No. This kind of questions is not welcomed here, please go through the [**Help Center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand what and how you should ask here.

Comment: well.. I apologize for it.. i actually need to know how to start...!!

Comment: Then please share with us your attempts.

Comment: Does it have to be a shell script? This isn't the kind of task that shells are suitable for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your puzzle is fun so here's a code:

```
#!/bin/bash

t=qwerty

echo '---- one dot ----'

for (( i = 1; i < ${#t}; ++i )); do
    echo "${t:0:i}.${t:i}"
done

echo '---- two dots ----'

for (( i = 1; i < (${#t} - 1); ++i )); do
    for (( j = i + 1; j < ${#t}; ++j )); do
        echo "${t:0:i}.${t:i:j - i}.${t:j}"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
---- one dot ----
q.werty
qw.erty
qwe.rty
qwer.ty
qwert.y
---- two dots ----
q.w.erty
q.we.rty
q.wer.ty
q.wert.y
qw.e.rty
qw.er.ty
qw.ert.y
qwe.r.ty
qwe.rt.y
qwer.t.y
```

See the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for everything.

Comment: thanks for the code.... btw you have provided the output for the two examples of the question... but what about the other combinations ?? do we have to use nested loops and read character by character ?

Comment: I'll check and modify the code and see if this solves my query.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code, but I can guide you to the answer.

I assume you want to consider all possible number of dots, not just 1 or 2, but 3, 4, ... , up to the length of the string - 1.

For each character in the string up until the last, there are two possibilities: there is a dot or there is not a dot.  So for an `n` character string, there are O(2^(n-1)) possibilities.

You could write a for loop that goes through all 2^(n-1) possibilities.  Each one of these corresponds to a single output with dots after letters.

Let `i` be an iteration of the for loop.  Then have an internal `j` loop that goes 1 to n-1.  If the `j`th bit is 1, then put a dot after the `j`th letter.